# I'm looking for a science fiction novel, from the 1960s or 1970s,with an odd picture of a man in a twisted sort of fetal position on the cover

Tags: story-identification, books

It was a paperback. I think it was German (translated into English) but I'm not sure.It was about defeated Germans after WW II developing psychic powers and /or mutating into something non-human. I think it was a series. I saw this as a little kid and it's been stuck in my mind for years.

I don't think it was Perry Rhodan. Possibly the Lensman series but none of these fit the scenario  or the cover art.

Comment: Were they just Germans, or were they specifically Nazis?

Comment: I think Germans in general. The cover picture was surrealistic, a guy curled up and in a rocking position.